# Laravel 5 include view with variable

Tags: laravel, variables, view, include, helper

I have two view files, **city_update** and  **create_update_city** and a **helpers.php** file which i have configured and it works fine.

**city_update** contains a form which at some point includes **create_update_city** which is used to call the functions declared in the **helpers.php**.

The form has a button and i need the button text sting to be passed through an array when i include **create_update_city** but i get a error *"Undefined variable: submitButtonText in create_update_city.blade.php"*. I think it happens because the helpers.php is called before the include and it has no value for the submitButtonText variable but i cant think of a way to solve this.

**city_update.blade.php** - contains :

```html
{{ Form::model($city , array('action'=>'CityController@create','class'=>'form-horizontal','method'=>'PATCH')) }}
        
@include('layouts.create_update_city' , ['submitButtonText '=>"Redakto"])

{{ Form::close() }}
```

**create_update_city.blade.php** - contains :

```html
{!! 
    submit([
        "name"  => $submitButtonText ,
        "class" => "btn btn-primary" 
    ]) 
!!}
```

**helpers.php** file has a **submit** functions which contains :

```html
Form::submit( $input['name'] , array('class' => $input['class'] ))
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove space in `['submitButtonText '=>"Redakto"]` after `submitButtonText`:

```
@include('layouts.create_update_city' , ['submitButtonText'=>"Redakto"])
```